# How to pass the date picker (or just the date) to show the date on textfield in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I want show a date picker view on keyboard. I am doing this using UITextField extension.

My code:

```
extension UITextField {

//... other functions

func showDatePicker(){
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

    let toolbar = UIToolbar();
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Pronto", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(UITextField.doneDatePicker(_:)))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancelar", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(UITextField.donePicker))
    toolbar.setItems([cancelButton,spaceButton,doneButton], animated: false)

    self.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

    self.inputView = datePicker

}

@objc func doneDatePicker(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker){

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    self.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    self.endEditing(true)
}
}
```

My problem is when I tap "Pronto" button and the function doneDatePicker is executed. I need pass the UIDatePicker (or just the date) to show the date on textfield but I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem date]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103488850'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply subclass UITextField and declare your datepicker as a property of your UITextField, override didMoveToSuperview method and do the customisation there:

```
class DateField: UITextField {
    var date: Date?
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let done = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Pronto", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneAction))
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancelar", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction))
        toolbar.setItems([cancel,space,done], animated: false)
        inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        inputView = datePicker
    }
    @objc func cancelAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        endEditing(true)
    }
    @objc func doneAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        date = datePicker.date
        text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: The linked questions were duplicates. The OP broke the rule how to specify target/action selectors

Comment: Yes but the solution was not in the linked question

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pass extra parameters through selectors. Why you are passing date picker  to

```
@objc func doneDatePicker(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker)
```

Replace

```
 let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
```

with

```
 var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

and put it as shared instance in a singleton class.
then access datePicker inside the function.

Comment: But I'm doing this using UITextField extension, then I can't declare a variable global because extensions may not contain stored properties. Any suggest?

Comment: In showDatePicker() pass the parameter as datePicker. showDatePicker(datePicker: UIDatePicker)

Comment: Then call it inside VC as  textField.showDatePicker(datePicker: datePicker)

Comment: The showDatePicker functions is right, my problem is when I tap "Pronto" button to set the textfield text with new date, I can't pass the date picker to action function to manage it.

Comment: you can declare var datePicker: UIDatePicker!  above class declaration after import UIKit. then you can access it in textField extension also.

Comment: @RahulDasgupta you shouldn't suggest OP to declare his objects at global scope. What if OP has a lot of date fields in his UI? Even if there were only one date field in his whole app you should suggest him to create a shared instance singleton class.

Comment: Thanks dude I forgot about Singleton classes