# 2 UITextField and 1 UIDatePicker: How can I let UIDatePicker know where to display the .date

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have 2 UITextField calling the same UIDatePicker, how can I let the UIDatePicker know which one of the UITextField called when comes time to set the picked date in the textfield?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing what you have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47793834/2303865

Answer (score 0):

You can use controller/UI element tag number for these types of scenarios.You can give a specific tag number (Int value) for the textfield on viewDidLoad() or through the stroybaord.

From Storyboard :-

[image]

Give different tag number to the two textfiled

From Code :-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   self.texField1.tag = 1
   self.textField.tag = 2
}
```

Then you can identify each textfield by calling

```
 if textfield.tag == 1 {

 } else textfield.tag == 2 {

 }
```